# Not loading custom bitmaps for toolbar in C++

Tags: c++, winapi, toolbar

I'm working on a WINAPI application, and I created a toolbar using `CreateWindowEx()`.
And as you know, to load custom icons for the toolbar's buttons, you should specify the bitmap which contains the a list of icons in the resource file, and join it to the toolbar

(By using `tbab.nID = IDB_LIST;`). BUT IT DOESN'T WORK!

resource.h:

```
#define IDB_LIST 101
```

resource.rc:

```
#include "resource.h"
IDB_LIST BITMAP "list.bmp"
```

main.cpp:

```
            TBBUTTON tbb[1];
            TBADDBITMAP tbab;

            tbab.hInst = g_hInst;
            tbab.nID = IDB_LIST;

            hToolBar = CreateWindowEx(TBSTYLE_EX_MIXEDBUTTONS, TOOLBARCLASSNAME, NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | TBSTYLE_TOOLTIPS, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                hWnd, (HMENU)IDC_MAIN_TOOL, g_hInst, NULL);

            SendMessage(hToolBar, TB_BUTTONSTRUCTSIZE, (WPARAM)sizeof(TBBUTTON), 0);
            SendMessage(hToolBar, TB_ADDBITMAP, (WPARAM)1, (LPARAM)&tbab);
            SendMessage(hToolBar, TB_SETMAXTEXTROWS, 0, 0);

            ZeroMemory(&tbb, sizeof(tbb));
            tbb[0].iBitmap = 0;
            tbb[0].fsState = TBSTATE_ENABLED;
            tbb[0].fsStyle = TBSTYLE_BUTTON;
            tbb[0].idCommand = ID_FILE_NEW;
            tbb[0].iString = (INT_PTR)"Create a new file";

            SendMessage(hToolBar, TB_ADDBUTTONS, sizeof(tbb)/sizeof(TBBUTTON), (LPARAM)&tbb);
```

Comment: Try sending `TB_SETBITMAPSIZE` before you add the bitmap.

Comment: Uh oh, doesn't work :(

Comment: If the toolbar was created using the CreateWindowEx function, you must send the TB_BUTTONSTRUCTSIZE message to the toolbar before sending TB_ADDBITMAP.

Comment: And what are you seeing?!

Comment: check if the return value for `SendMessage(hToolBar, TB_ADDBITMAP, 0, (LPARAM)&tbab)` is >= zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used another way to load bitmap.

Modified code (only the custom bitmap section is provided):

```
HWND CreateSimpleToolbar(HWND hWnd)
{
    TBBUTTON tbb[1];
    TBADDBITMAP tbab;

    const int bitmapSize = 32;
    const int ImageListID = 0;

    hToolBar = CreateWindowEx(TBSTYLE_EX_MIXEDBUTTONS, TOOLBARCLASSNAME, NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | TBSTYLE_TOOLTIPS | TBSTYLE_WRAPABLE, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        hWnd, NULL, g_hInst, NULL);
    HBITMAP bitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImage((HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_HINSTANCE), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_LIST), IMAGE_BITMAP, 32, 32, NULL);

    SendMessage(hToolBar, TB_BUTTONSTRUCTSIZE, (WPARAM)sizeof(TBBUTTON), 0);

    ZeroMemory(&tbb, sizeof(tbb));
    tbb[0].iBitmap = 0;
    tbb[0].fsState = TBSTATE_ENABLED;
    tbb[0].fsStyle = TBSTYLE_BUTTON;
    tbb[0].idCommand = ID_FILE_NEW;
    tbb[0].iString = (INT_PTR)L"Create a new file";

    g_hImageList = ImageList_Create(bitmapSize, bitmapSize,   // Dimensions of individual bitmaps.
        ILC_COLOR24 | ILC_MASK,   // Ensures transparent background.
        1, 0);
    ImageList_Add(g_hImageList, bitmap, NULL);

    SendMessage(hToolBar, TB_SETIMAGELIST,
        (WPARAM)ImageListID,
        (LPARAM)g_hImageList);

    SendMessage(hToolBar, TB_ADDBUTTONS, sizeof(tbb) / sizeof(TBBUTTON), (LPARAM)&tbb);

    SendMessage(hToolBar, TB_AUTOSIZE, 0, 0);
    return hToolBar;
}
```

Debug:

[image: 2]

I mainly use [ImageList_Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-imagelist_add?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

> Adds an image or images to an image list.

Refer :[How to use custom icons for toolbars in winapi programming](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21743203/11128312)

> Create an image list using ImageList_Create(), add your
>   BMP image to it using `ImageList_Add()` or `ImageList_ReplaceIcon()`,
>   associate it with the toolbar using `TB_SETIMAGELIST`, and then you
>   can set `tbb[0].iBitmap` to the BMP's index within the image list.

**But surely, the picture ID is no problem. I load the BMP image into the resource file, and then load the image successfully.**